# How to debug a 3rd party library when moving to requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, kendo-ui

I moved a project to requirejs and everything works fine except for a detail with a 3rd party library (which is not an AMD module). I would like to know any suggestions on the techniques to follow to resolve these type of issues when using requirejs.

The 3rd party library is kendo-ui and the issue is when trying to change the locale by calling kendo.culture("es-MX"). The function is being called without an error but it does not work as supposed.

The way to use this is kendo is by:
    loading kendo       : 
    loading the locale  : 
    calling the function: kendo.culture("es-MX");

I checked and the only global variable that gets exported is named kendo by the kendo script. I cannot see any global variable added by kendo.culture.es-MX.min.js

The setup I did in my main script for requirejs is:

```
    require.config({
                 paths: {
                     jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.7.2.min',
                     signals: 'lib/signals',
                     hasher: 'lib/hasher',
                     crossroads: 'lib/crossroads',
                     kendo: 'lib/kendo.web.min',
                     kendoCulture: 'lib/cultures/kendo.culture.es-MX.min',
                     knockout: 'lib/knockout-2.1.0',
                     knockout_kendo: 'lib/knockout-kendo.min',
                     underscore: 'lib/underscore-min',
                     json2: 'lib/json2',
                     faclptController: 'faclpt/faclptController',
                     FacturaViewModel: 'faclpt/FacturaViewModel',
                     ConfigViewModel: 'faclpt/ConfigViewModel',
                     domReady: 'lib/domReady'
                 },
                 shim: {
                     'kendoCulture': {
                         deps: ['kendo']
                     },
                     'kendo' : {
                         exports: 'kendo'
                     }
                 }

               });

               require([
                   'require',
                   'jquery',
                   'knockout',
                   'knockout_kendo',
                   'underscore',
                   'json2',
                   'faclptController',
                   'FacturaViewModel',
                   'ConfigViewModel',
                   'domReady'
                   ], function (
                       require,
                       $,
                       ko,
                       knockout_kendo,
                       _,
                       json2,
                       faclptController,
                       FacturaViewModel,
                       ConfigViewModel,
                       domReady) {

                           // Start of Main Function
                           domReady(function () {

                           kendo.culture("es-MX");


                               // knockout Bindings
                               ko.applyBindings(FacturaViewModel, document.getElementById('Proceso'));

                               ko.applyBindings(ConfigViewModel, document.getElementById('Configuracion'));

                           });


               });
```

So what else should I look for?

I would appreciate any techniques or tips on how to debug requirejs

Comment: So far the techniques I have followed are check the global variables defined by the 3rd party libraries and make sure that you can see them on the module that you are importing. Check that the actual library is being downloaded. I found that for a good part of my testing the shim was not downloading the library ??!!

Comment: BTW. The error above can be solved by copying the whole content of the kendo.culture.es-MX.min script just before kendo.culture(). Now, I just have to find out a way to do this type of inlining with RequireJS.